# Throw new InterruptedException() instead .join()

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

I try to stop a thread using .interrupt() method.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            System.out.println(threadName + " generated " + i);
            if (counter.isInterrupted()) {
                counter.join();
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

What I do not understand is that instead of this code:

```
if (counter.isInterrupted()) {
    counter.join();
}
```

If I throw an InterruptedException it works as well.

```
if (counter.isInterrupted()) {
    throw new InterruptedException();
}
```

What I do not understand is why I would choose one instead of another one. Also I've seen some approaches where people use an volatile boolean variable too. Is is safer than my approach?

Comment: if you call `join()`, you wait for this thread to complete. If you call `join()` on the current thread it will wait forever.

Comment: You don't need to interrupt a thread just as it dies. Using `break;` to break the loop would be fine.

Comment: I want to stop the thread when the user presses a certain button...

Comment: Re, "I want to stop the thread..." Don't ever thing of _doing_ things to running threads: Write code that _asks_ the thread to do whatever it is. Don't think of `t.interrupt()` as a function that stops a thread: Think of it as a way to get a thread's attention. The most common reason for `t.interrupt()` is to ask thread `t` to gracefully shut itself down, where "gracefully" means, without leaving shared variables in any bogus state that will break the rest of the program. You may have to write handlers for the `InterruptedException` to ensure the "gracefully" part.

Comment: Also note: `t.interrupt()` will _not_ cause an exception in a thread that never waits for anything. If your thread does nothing but computation, then you'll have to write code that periodically checks `isInterrupted()` if you want `t.interrupt()` to have any effect on it.

Comment: Actually my button exit from program. It asks the user if he wants stop the running threads or not...

Comment: @JohnR. If you `break;` out of the loop, the task will end normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `InterruptedException` is meant to indicate that the current thread has been interrupted in the course of an operation.  The issue with your second option is that you are throwing the exception on the basis of some *other* thread being interrupted.  This will cause the wrong impression to be made by calling code.

As a rule of thumb, when you catch an `InterruptedException`, you should do one of three things:

- Rethrow it (without a wrapper exception), so that callers know of the interruption
- Re-set the `interrupt()`, so that the fact that this thread was interrupted is maintained
- Handle the interruption (usually by cleaning up and shutting down the thread)